# how to create internal frame in netbeans platform?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I created class NewProject extends JInternalFrame. Then I create New...Action named "NEW", localised in File menu. I put code `NewProject p = new NewProject(); p.setVisible(true);` to the ActionPerformed method of the action.

But when I run the module and click "NEW" in file menu, nothing appears.
Where can be problem?

**EDIT:**
I partially solved it by code:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    JInternalFrame f = new JInternalFrame();
    f.setSize(500, 500);
    f.setVisible(true);
    JDesktopPane p = new JDesktopPane();
    p.add(f);

   //WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow().setTitle("fFF");
   WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow().add(p)
```

}

but GUI is broken. When I create new internal frame, the black background appears as I move by that frame.
Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want create internal frame in netbeans platform. When I run module and select action which create that internal frame, I want that frame appear

Comment: You should first create a top level container like JFrame and then add the JInternalFrame within the JFrame.

Comment: but toplevel container is  created by netbeans and I cannot find how to get to it.

Answer (score 2):

The customary `Container` for [`JInternalFrame`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) is [JDesktopPane](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html). The article [*How to Use Internal Frames*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) outlines the essentials, and you may like this short [example](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/msg/2e1b14bcad9bd7fa) of using `Action` and `JMenu` in this context.

Although the NetBean's GUI editor is appealing, you may want to become more comfortable using Swing components first.

Addendum: You can't add one [*Top-Level Container*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) like `JFrame` to another like [JDesktopPane](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html), but you can add any number of [`JInternalFrame`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) instances to a [JDesktopPane](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html). Try the [demo](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorialJWS/uiswing/components/ex6/InternalFrameDemo.jnlp) to see how it works.

Addendum: Ah, you mean [*NetBeans Platform*](http://platform.netbeans.org/). Sorry, I've not used it.

Comment: But the problem is I do not know how to get main window's desktoppane or whatever where I can attach my JFrame. I am speaking about Netbeans Platform.

Comment: Sorry about the broken tutorial link. See above for more.

Comment: I am not sure If you understand me (i am not english speaking). I know  how to create internal frame when I create my own main window. But I do not know how to get my internal frame into pre-created main window of Netbeans Plaform

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you are looking for is here: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/jdesktoppane,-jinternalframe,-and-topcomponent

There Geertjan Wielenga show an example using a `TopComponent` with a `JDesktopPane` inside, where you can attach some `JInternalFrame`.

```
...
...
...
private JDesktopPane jdpDesktop;
private int openFrameCount = 0;
public DemoTopComponent() {
    initComponents();
    setName(NbBundle.getMessage(DemoTopComponent.class, "CTL_DemoTopComponent"));
    setToolTipText(NbBundle.getMessage(DemoTopComponent.class, "HINT_DemoTopComponent"));
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    jdpDesktop = new JDesktopPane();
    createFrame(); // Create first window
    createFrame(); // Create second window
    createFrame(); // Create third window
    //Add the JDesktop to the TopComponent
    add(jdpDesktop);
}
protected void createFrame() {
    MyInternalFrame frame = new MyInternalFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    jdpDesktop.add(frame);
    try {
        frame.setSelected(true);
    } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {
        }
 }

class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {
    int xPosition = 30, yPosition = 30;
    public MyInternalFrame() {
        super("IFrame #" + (++openFrameCount), true, // resizable
            true, // closable
            true, // maximizable
            true);// iconifiable
        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocation(xPosition / openFrameCount, yPosition /   openFrameCount);
        // Add some content:
        add(new JLabel("hello IFrame #" + (openFrameCount)));
       }
}
...
...
...
```

Comment: Can you at least provide an example of how that was done? If that link disappears in X years time, and someone comes across this question with the hopes of finding a solution, will your post provide them with a solution? By adding the relevant example, the quality of your answer goes from 0(should have been a comment) to 10(an actual answer/solution)

Comment: Ah perfect - you finished your edit as I posted my comment. I am retracting my flag, and +1. This is what an answer should look like. Well done.

Comment: @user8356314 Same here, I retracted my flag and deleted my previous comments (which are now irrelevant).