# Swing - Menu With Open Windows

Tags: java, swing, dialog, jmenuitem

For user convenience, and after reading user interface guidelines, I would like a JMenu with Items as open Windows in my program, e.g. different (non-modal) dialogs/frames.

The menu lists the windows, and focuses them when clicked (Mentioned in Mac Human Interface Guidelines). They are common in most programs.

How could I do this? So far I think using a *HashMap* and *WindowAdapters*, that add and remove when windows appear, but I can't work out how to implement this.

Note - I have a main frame, and dialogs that are called in separate classes from the main frame which would have the menu. Sorry, no especially relevant code that helps explain. I am aware of Window.getWindows() but unsure how this would be used.

Comment: Start by having a look at [`Window#getWindows`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getWindows())

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 2):

[*How to Use Actions*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) is a good choice "if you have two or more components that perform the same function." Compete examples include these:

- [`FileMenu`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4039359/230513), which illustrates a menu of files.
- [`ImageApp`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5129757/230513), which opens images from a menu bar or a context menu.
- [`InternalFrameFocus`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2440777/230513), a `JInternalFrame` example cited there shows how to use `setSelected()` in a menu's `Action`.

  ```
  Action action = new AbstractAction(name) {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
          try {
              MyFrame.this.setSelected(true);
          } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
  };
  ```